# Creating a new GD image stream and outputting an image

Tags: php, image, gd

```
<?php
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

The output is [image]

Now I want to know how to store this image on server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagepng() has a second parameter which is the filename.

See

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

> bool imagepng ( resource $image [, string $filename [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )
>
> filename
>
> The path to save the file to. If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.
>
> Note:
>
> NULL is invalid if the quality and filters arguments are not used.

Comment: its giving me option to download image

Comment: If you fill the second parameter with a string path of a correct and writable filename, then it saves the image directly.

The download file dialog appears (I can imagine) only in case the parameter is missing; therefore the raw image data gets output to the browser directly. Then, when the content-type meta header is wrong, the Save as.. dialog would appear.

So, both functionalities cannot work with a single imagepng() call; either the picture is displayed or the file is created.

You can get around this with the output buffer functions, I guess.

Comment: So, if you want to both display the image and save it in the same script, **either** first call ob_start(), call imagepng() without the filename, then ob_get_contents to get the image to a string (which you can write to a file), then ob_end_flush() to show the image to the user, **or** call the imagepng() twice (once without filename to display it, once with filename to save it)

Answer (score 0):

Displays the image and saves the file on my test server.

*You will need write permission on the directory you're saving to.*

```
...
imagepng($im);
imagepng($im, 'filename.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```